# Dual boot stopped working

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Simple user here. I have a ten-days-old Acer Aspire E15 (E5-575G-54Y1) which came with Windows and I installed Ubuntu 16.04. Dual boot used to work fine until today.

Today, I suddenly get only Windows. When I press <kbd>F12</kbd> at startup I get the screen with both boot options, I select grubx64efi, but I still boot into Windows. I change the boot order to have Ubuntu boot first, but I still get Windows. Btw the partitions look okay. (One additional strange detail is that when I first turned the computer on today I was automatically logged into Windows as administrator.)

Of course I haven't changed any setting knowingly. The only two things I did yesterday which *might* be relevant were these:

1. I activated McAfee in Windows
2. I ran the commands suggested in [this article](http://scienceblogs.com/gregladen/2016/06/23/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-to/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: May be an obvious question. But, have you disabled hibernation in Windows yet? Also, "fast boot" and/or "secure boot" disabled in the BIOS are a huge help with stable dual booting.

Comment: Disabling the BIOS secure boot solved it! Would you like to upgrade this to an answer? However, it was suggested to me that I also disable McAfee, and I guess it was the combination of these two actions that worked. (Ergo, McAfee created the problem.)

Comment: I'm just glad you got it working. Feel free to answer your own question. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by following two suggestions made to me (one in the comments above):

I uninstalled McAfee and disabled the secure boot in BIOS.

(For the record, the secure boot was enabled in the process of making Aspire E15 accept booting from somewhere other than the Windows partition.)

Comment: Did you mean "disabled the secure boot in BIOS"?

Comment: Fixed! (and 8 more characters required for this comment to be accepted)